# Group does not update when Itemsource is changed programatically - WPF, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datagrid, grouping

I have a datagrid which has bound a ObservableCollection.
The implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged works as it should. I grouped the DataGridView with a collectionview:

```
     CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dgVarConfig.ItemsSource).GroupDescriptions.Clear();
            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dgVarConfig.ItemsSource).GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("TopLevelGroup"));
            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dgVarConfig.ItemsSource).GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Group"));
            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dgVarConfig.ItemsSource).Refresh();
```

This works as expected but one problem.
When i change the "TopLevelGroup" in the datagrid, the grid refreshes and the groupassignment works correctly.
If i change it via WPF Window it doesnt doesnt refresh the grid.

Code:

```
public void changeGroup(String group, VarConfig selectedVarConfig)
    {
        selectedVarConfig.TopLevelGroup = group;
    }
```

To be clear: The groupcell in the grid changes, but the assignment doesnt work automatically. If i doubleclick the cell and exit edit mode it jumps to the correct group.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgVarConfig" ItemsSource="{Binding VarConfigList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedVarConfig, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="8,56,557,80" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" CanUserAddRows="False" LayoutUpdated="dgVarConfig_LayoutUpdated" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" PreviewKeyDown="dgVarConfig_PreviewKeyDown" BeginningEdit="dgVarConfig_BeginningEdit" CellEditEnding="dgVarConfig_CellEditEnding" SelectionChanged="dgVarConfig_SelectionChanged" LoadingRow="dgVarConfig_LoadingRow">
```

It would work with `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dgVarConfig.ItemsSource).Refresh();` but thats not an option because the grid is very complex and does take a while to refresh.

Any ideas?

Comment: if(datagrid.Items.NeedReferesh) datagrid.Items.Referesh()
 try that

Comment: does not work. but thanks

Comment: try this, this might work....
datagrid.ItemsSource = null; datagrid.ItemsSource = someData;

Comment: code like this would work, but the i cant use it because it takes a while to load the grid

Answer (score 0):

Your ItemsSource should be

```
ItemsSource="{Binding VarConfigList,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```